# Design implementation about the way of using HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

When showing accounts in the GUI, I need to show primary accounts ( for secondary accounts )
There can be multiple secondary accounts for each primary account.

I am trying to save the primary to secondary accounts information in the HashMap. Because, that needs to be retrieved later.

While saving, I also need to save secondary account instruction. So, I need to save two objects with key as Primary account.

```
1) Secondary Account
2) Secondary Instruction.
```

I have equals and hashcode overridden for account and instruction objects.

I am trying to use Primary account hashcode as key and value as a List of Object[2]

-- Initialization

```
private static final Map<Integer, ArrayList<Object[]>> primaryToSecondaryAcct = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Object[]>>();
```

-- Putting values

```
final Object[] acctInstr = new Object[2];
acctInstr[0] = acct;
acctInstr[1] = instr;
if(primaryToSecondaryAcct.get(getExistingAccount().hashCode()) != null) {
    primaryToSecondaryAcct.get(getExistingAccount().hashCode()).add(acctInstr);
} else {
    final ArrayList<Object[]> acctInstrList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    acctInstrList.add(acctInstr);
    primaryToSecondaryAcct.put(getExistingAccount().hashCode(), acctInstrList);
}
```

*I am wondering if this is correct and if there a better way of doing it. Could you suggest?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Object[]>>
```

why not have

```
Map<Account, SecondaryInfo>
```

At the moment you're storing a collection against the key, and you have to manage that, iterate through it etc. when you pull it from the `Map`. I think it's much better to create a suitable abstraction and delegate to it. That abstraction will look after validation, iteration etc. in one location, rather than you having to worry about it each time you access the `Map`.

Remember - OO is about *telling objects to do things for you*, not asking them for info and doing it yourself.

I would replace your `Integer` representation of an account by a specific `Account` object. otherwise you're going to have to manage lots of integers representing different types, and it's very easy to mix these up. Typing them (albeit using a trivial class) means you can refactor trivially using automated tools and easily determine types without resorting to naming conventions.

Comment: I didn't realize the fact that two objects can have same hashCode. Thanks for the recommendation ( remember stuff )! That helps.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `Account` as key, as hashcode can be the same for two different objects.

Comment: Actually, `Integer.hashCode()` returns the `int` value of the `Integer`, so it's impossible to have the same hash for two `Integer` objects. There's still the possibility for collisions of course (table size isn't equal to the key space), but not because of equal hashes from the `Integer` objects.

Comment: @Brian He doesn't use `Integer.hashCode()`, but `Account.hashCode()`, which is a different thing.

Comment: In his question, he was using `Map<Integer, ArrayList<Object[]>>`, so no, he wasn't. In the selected answer, he will be.

Comment: @Brian `primaryToSecondaryAcct.put(getExistingAccount().hashCode(), acctInstrList);` So the `Integer` that is used as key is the hashCode of the `Account`. So it is possible to have two different accounts with the same hashCode and the map would consider them equal.

Comment: Also, I agree, that's an issue since they would indeed be considered equal by the map in this case +1

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you want is a [`MultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), which you can find in the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library from Google. This is similar to a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, and maps a key to multiple values for you so you don't have to reinvent that.

Next, replace `Object[]` with your own custom class:

```
public class SecondaryInformation {
    private SecondaryAccount secondaryAccount;
    private SecondaryInstruction secondaryInstruction;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

So you'll have a `MultiMap<Integer, SecondaryInformation>`. Here's [some wiki info](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) on the `MultiMap`.

Answer (score 2):

If for both `Primary` and `Secondary` accounts you have classes as follows:

```
public class PrimaryAccount 
{
    int id;
    private List<SecondaryAccount> secondaryAccounts;   
}

public class SecondaryAccount
{
    int id;
    private List<String> instructions;
    PrimaryAccount primaryAccount;
}
```

Then, perhaps you will not even need `HashMap`. However, you may still want to maintain a `Hashmap` for quick look up of Accounts:
`HashMap<Integer,PrimaryAccoount>` , where you will store account id and primary account.

This makes the implementation cleaner. How ever you do need write classes for `Primary` and `Secondary` accounts.